# HP TouchSmart 520 touchscreen not working on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: hp

Getting my HP TouchSmart 520 Desktop on Ubuntu 18.10 to work the touchscreen.I've tried the TouchSmart 600 Touchscreen driver with no success.

Comment: Where did you get the driver? Was it a Linux driver?

Comment: It's a linux driver but for the 600.  Couldn't find one for the 520.

Comment: Can you give a link to it?

Comment: Did you have no success installing it or no success getting it to work after installation? This link has some information on both: https://answers.launchpad.net/nwfermi/+question/665183